# users/questions/answers count on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

stackexchange.com currently lists

```
1.1 million users 5.3 million questions 1.8 million answers
```

I thought this have been much more earlier, and I checked it through http://web.archive.org/web/20121209091909/https://stackexchange.com/:

```
2.6 million users 5 million questions 9.6 million answers
```

What happened to all the users and answers?

Comment: The 1.8m answers is almost definitely wrong. It looks to be a bad query... (or stats being added to a table going slightly wrong)

Comment: Might be related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164580/number-of-answers-and-users-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Bart thanks for the link, meanwhile both statistics show reasonable numbers again. If you like, phrase a quick answer (temporary glitch, no need to report immediately etc.) according to your comments in the other answer, and I will happily accept it.